# Database join where

Tags: sql, join

Database

Users

| id | lastname | firstname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sardor | Sattarov |
| 2 | Nurmuhammad | To’xtayev |
| 3 | Jasur | Sattarov |

Group_items

| id | student_id | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 55 |
| 2 | 1 | 55 |
| 3 | 2 | 11 |

Return
**example 1**

**condition**

`users.id == group_items.student_id` do not publish a table that satisfies this desire  `group_items.id == 55`

| id | lastname | firstname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Jasur | Sattarov |

**example 2**

**condition**

`users.id == group_items.student_id` do not publish a table that satisfies this desire  `group_items.id == 11`

| id | lastname | firstname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sardor | Sattarov |
| 3 | Jasur | Sattarov |

Comment: Can you elaborate on what query you are trying to execute when you are getting null in return?

Comment: There should be 6 columns in the result data.  Two of them would have the (ambiguous) label `id`.

Comment: Without the sample query, you don't have a question.  Normally, a question about SQL should be tagged with the [tag:sql] tag.  And, ideally, it should be tagged with the DBMS you're using, though in this case, it doesn't matter much as the SQL isn't using anything that's likely to be DBMS-specific.

Comment: The conditions in the SQL mean that only the row for Jasur Sattarov should be printed.  Expecting a different result means there is confusion somewhere — it isn't clear why you'd expect that output row to be omitted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name — except that the `WHERE gi.student_id IS NULL` condition eliminates all those users which match a row in the joined table.

Comment: `users.id == group_items.student_id`   equal table should not be printed.

Comment: print another table

Comment: Provided `Group_items.student_id` and `Group_items.group_id` declared `NOT NULL`,  `gi.student_id IS NULL AND gi.group_id <> 5` will return no rows at all.

Comment: You don't have the condition `users.id == group_items.student_id` in the SQL; it is not clear what you mean, therefore.  There is an ON condition written `u.id = gi.student_id` which is the same condition.  You're using a LEFT JOIN, though, which means that a row for Jasur Sattarov is created in the join result with NULL for the columns from `group_item`.  The WHERE conditions accept that row.

Comment: The code I wrote did not work

Comment: @Serg — the LEFT join can generate NULL values in the result set (and does).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , if both columns are declared NOT NULL, and left join returned oneof them NULL, the other is NULL too , so `<>` fails.

Comment: Try to SELECT * from group_items gi LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = gi.student_id

Comment: `SELECT * from group_items gi LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = gi.student_id ` in which case null must be returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like  you want OR instead of AND.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN group_items gi ON u.id = gi.student_id 
WHERE
    gi.student_id IS NULL 
    OR gi.group_id <> 5
```

Studends without a group plus studends in all groups but 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` statements in SQL

For Example
for return 1:

`SELECT * FROM users u left join group_items gi on gi.student_id = u.id`

this query will return all students with their group_id
for filter by group you can use where statement.

`SELECT * FROM users u left join group_items gi on gi.student_id = u.id where gi.group_id<>11`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users u left join group_items gi on gi.student_id = u.id where gi.group_id=11` should not be published in such a case

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

Example 1:

```
SELECT
U.ID,U.LASTNAME,U.FIRSTNAME 
FROM 
USERS U
LEFT JOIN 
GROUP_ITEMS G
ON U.ID=G.STUDENT_ID
WHERE G.GROUP_ID <>55
```

Example 2:

```
SELECT
U.ID,U.LASTNAME,U.FIRSTNAME  
FROM 
USERS U
LEFT JOIN 
GROUP_ITEMS G
ON U.ID=G.STUDENT_ID
WHERE G.GROUP_ID <>11
```